# Why is my SQL query not working?

Tags: python, sql

I'm posting this, and getting this error:

```
c.execute("""update resulttest set category=""" + key + ", value=""" + str(value))

OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'composed' in 'field list'")
```

I am trying to update the columns category and field, composed is simply a value in category.

Why is this error coming up?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the actual query string you are composing?  (Hint: it's not correct.)

Comment: Also, please don't do things this way.  You open yourself to SQL injection problems.  Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use interpolation and parameterized queries for easier to read syntax, no escaping quotes or anything.

`c.execute("""update resulttest set category=?, value=?""", (key, value))`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/775399/594589

Answer (score 2):

```
// **mysql based**
string cmd = "UPDATE resulttest SET category=\"" + key + "\", value=\"" + str(value) + "\"";

// **sql based**
string cmd = "UPDATE resulttest SET category='" + key + "', value='" + str(value) + "'";

// make sure you command output a escaped format
// UPDATE resulttest SET category='test', value='test'
// UPDATE resulttest SET category="test", value="test"

c.execute(cmd);
```

Comment: I think you are barking up the wrong tree. String literals must be enclosed in single quotes within SQL.

Comment: @dbenham I have based on mysql, Why you just edit the answer to fix then?

Answer (score 2):

You might see something interesting if you generate the query string and then print it out before you try to execute it.  Have you tried that?

I think your quotation marks are probably not done correctly.  That is, perhaps you want the query to look like this:

`update resulttest set category='somekey', value='composed'`

I don't think that is what you'll get for the query string you are composing.