# Flask partial view for a list of items

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

If on most pages in the website I have a list of categories or recent articles that are loaded from the DB - how can I avoid duplicating code using flask and jinja2 ?

The way it is now, I have an html file which I include like :

```
{% include '/root/latest_articles.html' %}
```

And then every view has to pass the parameter (list of articles) to the template. I'd like to avoid this.

What's the best way to achieve this in Flask?

Thanks.

**Edit**

The "additional template context" would work .. I could export a function that loads the data from the DB and access it in the "latest_articles.html" template.

Is there another way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add [additional template context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors):

```
@app.context_processor
def additional_context():
    return {
        'content': get_page_content_context(request.endpoint, g.language),
        'hot_links': get_hot_links(),
    }
```

For templates code you can use [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) or [include](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include).

**UPD:**

At first try use [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance) and put your list of categories or recent articles in base template if your pages allow this.

You also can make template code just variable with `@app.context_processor', but I don't think that it's a good idea:

```
@app.context_processor
def additional_context():
    return {
        'recent_articles_markup': do_mark_safe(render_template(
            'root/latest_articles.html', articles=get_recent_articles()),
    }
```

Comment: Also consider using template inheritance instead of includes.

Answer (score 1):

My usual solution for such kind of stuff is Class inheritance with prepare function, please refer to my answer in other thread:

Different question, same solution.
[Dynamic navigation in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501518/dynamic-navigation-in-flask/15525226#15525226)

Comment: Cool, thank you - I'll definitely look into your solution too.