# Inserting Variables MySQL Using Python, Not Working

Tags: python, mysql, variables, python-2.7, insert

I want to insert the variable `bob`, and `dummyVar` into my table, `logger`. Now from what I can tell all I should need to do is, well what I have below, however this doesn't insert anything into my table at all. If I hard-code what should be written (using `'example'` then it writes example to the table, so my connection and syntax for inserting is correct to this point). Any help would be more than appreciated!

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password!',
                              host='Host', database='database')

cursor = conn.cursor()

bob = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"
dummyVar = "Variable Test"

loggit = ("""
        INSERT INTO logger (logged_info, dummy)
        VALUES
            (%s, %s)
    """, (bob, dummyVar))

cursor.execute(loggit)
conn.commit()
```

I have also tried this:

```
loggit = ("""
        INSERT INTO logger (logged_info, dummy)
        VALUES
            (%(bob)s,(Hello))
    """, (bob))
```

and:

```
bob = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"
dummyVar = "Variable Test"

loggit = ("""
        INSERT INTO logger (logged_info, dummy)
        VALUES
            (%s, %s)
    """, (bob, dummyVar))

cursor.execute(loggit, (bob, dummyVar))
conn.commit()


cursor.execute(loggit, (bob, dummyVar))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: In addition to your main problem (which Martijn Pieters answers), you've got another one in your last example: `(bob)` is not a tuple of one element, it's the same thing as `bob`. You need to write `(bob,)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the SQL statement and the parameters as separate arguments:

```
cursor.execute(loggit[0], loggit[1])
```

or use the [variable argument syntax (a splat, `*`)](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

```
cursor.execute(*loggit)
```

Your version tries to pass in a tuple containing the SQL statement and bind parameters as the only argument, where the `.execute()` function expects to find just the SQL statement string.

It's more usual to keep the two separate and perhaps store just the SQL statement in a variable:

```
loggit = """
        INSERT INTO logger (logged_info, dummy)
        VALUES
            (%s, %s)
    """
cursor.execute(loggit, (bob, dummyVar))
```

Comment: Shouldn't I close the brackets after """ ?

Comment: @StevenByrne In the last example, no, since there's no opening one and no second value, loggit is a string, not a tuple anymore.

Comment: @StevenByrne: No, there is no opening parens; the `"""` tripple-quoting string can span multiple lines on it's own just fine.

Comment: First, thank you for the help, but I'm still a bit confused, am I suppose to change only the cursor.execute(loggit) to cursor.execute(loggit, (bob, dummyVar)) Or am I suppose to also change the way I create my Insert variable? P.S. Will the same syntax work with a global variable?

Comment: @StevenByrne: You don't need to change the way you use SQL parameters, just how you call `execute()`, making sure you pass in 2 arguments.

Comment: I updated my code to what I have under "EDIT" above, but it still does not write to the database; did I miss something?

Comment: @StevenByrne: Yes, `loggit` is *still* a tuple. It should be just a string. Compare your version of `loggit` with mine.

Comment: Okay it works perfectly now! Thank you I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @MartijnPieters so if I have an integer say `i` how do I insert it in a table?

Comment: You'd use a single-item tuple: `.execute(statement, (i,))`.