# How to pass variables to MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL (ver. 5.5.31-0+wheezy1) and python (ver. 2.7.3) with the following statement:

```
q ="""INSERT INTO scale_equipment truck_id, product_id, driver_id, field_id, pit_id, harvest_equipment_id, weight, status VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",(truck_id, product_id, driver_id, field_id, pit_id, harvest_equipment_id, 0, status)
```

If I use:

```
q ="""INSERT INTO scale_equipment truck_id, product_id, driver_id, field_id, pit_id, harvest_equipment_id, weight, status VALUES ('002', 'CS', 'BG', 'HD1', 'T1', 'C1', 0, 'U')"""
```

it works fine, what I am I doing wrong to pass the variables in the SQL statement

I print out the q before it hits the execute query statement using the variables and this is what it looks like:

```
'INSERT INTO scale_equipment truck_id, product_id, driver_id, field_id, pit_id, harvest_equipment_id, weight, status VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', ('002', 'CS', 'BG', 'HD1', 'T1', 'C1', 0, 'U')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506643/inserting-variables-mysql-using-python-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters <strike>should</strike> must be passed in the second argument of `execute()`:

```
params = ('002', 'CS', 'BG', 'HD1', 'T1', 'C1', 0, 'U')
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 
                      scale_equipment 
                      (truck_id, product_id, driver_id, field_id, pit_id, harvest_equipment_id, weight, status) 
                  VALUES 
                       (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", params)
```

In this case you wouldn't worry about sql injections, mysqldb driver does escaping for you.