# Passing variables into a MySQL query using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a database with some records that have a date field of "05221999".  I am trying to do a SQL query from the input of the user based on just the month and year.  In this case I am interested in all the records with the month of 05 and the year of 1999.

Unfortunately, I can't get the Python/SQL syntax correct.  Here is my code so far:

```
    def submitact(self):
        date = self.md.get()
        month = date[0:2]
        year = date[2:7]

        db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Code` = 'RM' AND `Date` LIKE %s'_'%s", (month, year))

        results = cursor.fetchall()
        print(results)

        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

I've done several variations on the SELECT statement and they either return errors or nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variables to MYSQL using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833865/how-to-pass-variables-to-mysql-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet below, I used f-string style to format the query string

```
[...]
query = f"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Code` = 'RM' AND LEFT(`Date`, 2) = '{month}' AND RIGHT(`Date`, 4) = '{year}'"
cursor.execute(query)
[...]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) unless the interpolated variables are generated completely internally (and even still using a parameterized query would be better)

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
query = "SELECT * 'table' WHERE 'Code' = 'RM' AND 'Date' LIKE '%{0}_{1}'".format(month, year)
cursor.execute(query)
```

In this way, 'query' variable value will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'Code' = 'RM' AND 'Date' LIKE '%05_1999'"
```

For more information about string formatting, let's have a look to [Python String Formatting Best Practices - Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: This answer is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) unless the interpolated variables are generated completely internally (and even still using a parameterized query would be better)