# How to use select statements with variables in mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to use a select statement with a variable within the where clause. Ive done resarch on this looking at [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) and [Inserting Variables MySQL Using Python, Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506643/inserting-variables-mysql-using-python-not-working). Ive tried to implement the solutions provided but its not working. Error code

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Heres the code:

```
name = input("Write your name")
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol=?", name)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay Spike7 this is exactly what is ideal,

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol=%s", (name,))
```

or

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol=?", (name,))
```

The accepted answer at [the first link you given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)  explain evertything.

Comment: Still getting syntax errors, shoudi take away the symbol?

Comment: @Spike7 the query you have written mean select all the names from workers table if the value in symbol column matches the value of the name variable

Comment: Yeah it was my fault. When i was looking at the questions it said  symbol and i thought it was some mysql language. i changed it to name and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL libraries use `%s` as the placeholder.

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol=%s", name)
```

Despite the similarity, this isn't string substitution.

Comment: I am afraid this will return a tuple

Comment: Thanks but Im getting a syntax error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1"

Comment: This works for me, having `datetime` instead of `name (string)`. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol={}".format(name))
```

This will only work as long as your variable name is not string

Answer (score -1):

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM workers WHERE symbol=%s"% name)
```

That's it

Comment: I get this error ysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'symbol' in 'where clause'

Comment: listen to your error... it suggests there is no such column as symbol.

Comment: @Rhys exactly, Spike recheck the columns available

Comment: This is **not** it. Do not recommend this, ever.

Comment: @DanielRoseman your explaination will help us understand python better.

Comment: @KishorPawar @DanielRoseman, I believe Dan's point is that using `%s` instead of `?` means you have no protection against SQL Injection.

Comment: @Rhys oh...with ` %s` this any string can be replaced.