# Python MySQLdb execute table variable (Scrapy)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, scrapy, mysql-python

First things first. I am runing my Scrapy scripts(version: 0.16.2) on Python 2.7.2+. The problem that I have is with pipe files and SQL syntax that I generate using  MySQLdb library.
Here is code that I am trying to run:

```
class basketpipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="blabla", passwd="blabla", db="basketball", host="blabla")
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self,item, spider):
    #declare variables for item elements
    Game_id=item['game_id']
    Attendance=item['attendance']
    Referees=item['referees']

    #form sql for database implementing variables above into the SQL        
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO BasketGame (Game_id,Referees,Attendance) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (Game_id,Referees,Attenance))
    self.conn.commit()
    return item
```

And after I run my script I have this from in the shell :

```
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.2 started (bot: basketbase)
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, 

CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: basketpipeline
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [basketsp] INFO: Spider opened
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [basketsp] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-11-14 00:32:59+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-11-14 00:33:01+0200 [basketsp] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=46&s%09code=E2013> (referer: None)
2013-11-14 00:33:01+0200 [basketsp] ERROR: Error processing %(item)s
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/vy/basketbase/basketbase/pipelines.py", line 41, in process_item
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO BasketGame (Game_id,Referees,Attendance) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (Game_id,Referees,Attendance))
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue
    _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'),("\'BULTO, VICENTE (ESP), SAHIN, TOLGA (ITA), VYKLICKY, ROBERT (CZE)\'",),("\'695\' at line 1')
```

The error:

```
`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'),("\'BULTO, VICENTE (ESP), SAHIN, TOLGA (ITA), VYKLICKY, ROBERT (CZE)\'",),("\'695\' at line 1`'
```

If I use only variable(any of those three) it is OK, It works fine, but when I start to use two or more I get the same problem.
I tried to solve this problem, read documentation:
http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Found nice answers here in Stackoverflow:
[Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)

But I get error if I use more than one variable. 
I know that I could missed something here, because I am new in Python/Scrapy/SQL, but it would be great if someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible Game_id is defined as a numeric type in the database, but you're not actually inserting a numeric value?

Comment: No, I checked the type is text.

Comment: could you dump the `Game_id`, `Referees`, `Attenance` variables and the schema of your `BasketGame` table?

Comment: `code`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BasketGame` (
  `Game_ID` text NOT NULL,
  `Attendance` text NOT NULL,
  `Referees` text NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: The original table has more variables, but I am testing only with those three to make a bit easer to read.

Comment: I was thinking you could also dump what's in the 3 variables `Game_id`, `Referees`, `Attenance`. I don't see how you could get `... \'),("\'BULTO, VICENT...` while only inserting 1 row (as you pipeline code does). Is the console log matching the pipeline code?

Comment: Ok here it is:<GET http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=46&s%09code=E2013> (referer: None)
[u'BULTO, VICENTE (ESP), SAHIN, TOLGA (ITA), VYKLICKY, ROBERT (CZE)'] [u'6950 (Tentative)'] [u'BULTO, VICENTE (ESP), SAHIN, TOLGA (ITA), VYKLICKY, ROBERT (CZE)']

Comment: For Game_ID and Referees it is the same thing as I don't know yet how to create it, but for the moment it is ok.