# How can be datetime formatted for mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, mysql-python

I want to send date and time from python to mysql.
Type of variable in MySQL is datetime.
I used year-month-day hour:minutes:seconds, but when i'm compiling it gives error after space (where time part is starting). Show, how i can make good value for this variable?

Error:

Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00:00,'',7000,NULL,NULL,'',NULL,'',5,'','','',NULL,'',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'',' at line 2

Comment: Can you give a more in depth error? That format matches that data type .

Comment: @eBrian added to problem text.

Comment: You should pass variables always through the driver and not put them into the query via string operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format should be:

```
 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS not YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS
```

About your error message, it starts in the middle of the datetime field, it seems. Try putting singlequotes around them.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6e0/1)</kbd>

Comment: sorry, it is already like this, there was error in description of problem. Fixed

Comment: @EminMastizada. Put singlequotes around the datetime value.

Comment: yes, actually answer for this question is this, it was stupid error) But problem not solved((( Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

All MySQL drivers for Python should be able to handle Python datetime objects natively.  You should never have to convert a datetime object to a string if you are using the MySQL driver properly.

See this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/775399/471671 (the second answer on the page).  The answer refers to security issues, which are the biggest reason to do it like this, but the other reason is that type conversion becomes automatic and you don't have to worry about string formatting your datetime objects (or anything else).