# Formatting sql %like%

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do the following query:

```
select count(*) from video where territories like %ZW%
```

Here is what I currently have, but it's raising an error:

```
for territory_code in ALL_TERRITORIES:
    sql = "select count(*) from video where territories like %{}%".format(territory_code)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how would I properly escale the %% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even better way to do this is as follows:

```
sql = "select count(*) from video where territories like %s"
cursor.execute(sql, ('%' + territory + '%',))
```

With this approach, you will be able to parameterize your query without worrying about escapes and, more importantly, without worrying about [security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables/775399#775399).

Answer (score 1):

They way you're doing this, you need a literal string with single quotes.

```
 select count(*) from video where territories like '%ZW%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the simple quotation marks after the like:

```
"select count(*) from video where territories like '%{}%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing '' single quotes around the %%. Use this instead:

```
"select count(*) from video where territories like '%{}%'"
```