# Using MySQL functions in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to use mysql functions date time function `str_to_date` in python. I need a guide on how to use mysql functions in python. `Raw_Data` is the name of the table.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) VALUES ('%s')""" % (STR_TO_DATE(date_time,'%d/%b/%Y:%T'))     
cursor.execute(sql)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'STR_TO_DATE' is not defined
```

Comment: that's a mysql function. what is it doing in your *python* code? you can't do that.

Comment: Don't be confused about where the calls happen.  If you call a MySQL function, it'll run on the database server, not in Python.  You can call it like a stored procedure in Python, but it'll execute on MySQL.

Comment: using it to extract date time object from string.I think it should return datetime object

Comment: @duffymo is suggesting that you wrap that all in quotes so that it is executed on the database server -- `sql = """INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) VALUES ('%s')"""% ("STR_TO_DATE(date_time,'%d/%b/%Y:%T')")
cursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: is there any way of using mysql functions in python.

Comment: Note the passing of two arguments to cursor.execute(), to stop SQL injections and other headaches. The SQL query with placeholders, and an iterable with the arguments.

Comment: You can use the sql function inside the SQL query string. It will then be executed by the database (other replies demonstrate this). If you want to convert a string into a datetime object in Python space, you can use datetime.strptime()

Comment: @JLLagrange WRAPING UP DIDNT'WORK FOR THIS...ERROR INCORRECT SQL SYNTAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query to:
**UPDATE:**

```
sql = """INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%b/%%Y:%%T'))"""% (date_time)
```

Comment: Even date format may be put in the SQL string: `sql = """INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%b/%%Y:%%T'))"""% (date_time,)`

Comment: It worked for me.I was using str_to_date function of mysql in the parameter.Got the mistake.thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First thing first: Never but Never use string formatting on a string and then pass the string to an SQL.

you can see the full explanation here  http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters (although it's for PostgreSQL this is a ground rule for DB programming).
Now want you want to do is to pass the MYSQL function as a parameter to the query
you can see more about how to do this in this post:

[Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)
and here: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#cursor-objects
now when you bind a date you wont need to convert it into a string and then back again.
so this code will be ok:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
sql = """ INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) Values ('%s')"""
cursor.execute(sql, (d,))
```

Now if you do wish to use a function in your code the function must be part of your sql not a parameter (or passed as a string parameter which is bad). This pesudo code should like this (I haven't ran it):

```
sql = """INSERT INTO RawData(DateTime) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('%s',%%d/%%b/%%Y:%%T'))"""
cursor.execute(sql, (d,))
```

Comment: Very good explanation. Parameters should always be passed as parameters!

Comment: Just a note: the second parameter of `execute` should be a sequence (tuple or list): so it should be `cursor.execute(sql, (d,))` or `cursor.execute(sql, [d])` - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries