# Insert python variables into rows of mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following code that parses data from an XML file.

```
import MySQLdb
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("report.xml")

parking_report = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("parking_report")[0]

sensors = parking_report.getElementsByTagName("sensor")

for sensor in sensors:
    id = sensor.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.data
    date = sensor.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].firstChild.data
    time = sensor.getElementsByTagName("time")[0].firstChild.data
    status = sensor.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].firstChild.data

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="pass",db="parking_report")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO report_table (id, date, time, status) VALUES (id, date, time, status)')

    print(id, date, time, status)
```

Right now, it runs without errors and returns the id, date, time and status of each parking sensor. However, my mySQL table (parking_report) also has the columns ID, Date, Time and Status. I want to insert the data of those variables into my table under those columns. (Note there are three separate sensors so I will need three rows of data in the end.)

When I run this it does not insert into my table. Please Help! Thank you.

Comment: Take note of the fact that you never actually pass your values into the `execute` function. What you want is a parametrized query. See this, which is a duplicate, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables.

Comment: commit is missing after inserting the record i believe ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any parameters to the query.

Instead of:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO report_table (id, date, time, status) VALUES (id, date, time, status)')
```

create a parameterized query:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO 
                   report_table 
                   (id, date, time, status) 
               VALUES
                   (%(id)s, %(date)s, %(time)s, %(status)s)""", 
            {'id': id, 
             'date': date, 
             'time': time, 
             'status': status})
```

There are other fixes you should apply to the code:

- define `db` and `cursor` variables before the loop so that you don't need to connect to the database and open a cursor on every iteration
- you should properly close the cursor and connection objects
- instead of calling `INSERT` database query on each iteration step, consider gathering the data into a list and then insert once after the loop

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well easiest way to insert python variables into rows of mysql table is:

```
cursor.execute(
   """INSERT INTO menu(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"""
   %(item1, item2, item3))
```

In your case:

```
cursor.execute(
   """INSERT INTO report_table(id, date, time, status) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
   %(id, date, time, status))
```