# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to create a SQL string from a python script.

this is the code:

```
sql_query = ('insert into ithelpdesk ' 
        '(id,display_id,subject,description,priority,status,requester_name,source,responder_id,due_by,updated_at,frDueBy,ticket_type,created_at)'
        ' values ('
        '"' + str(data['id']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['display_id']) + '",'
        '"' + data['subject'] + '",'
        '"' + data['description'] + '",'
        '"' + str(data['priority']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['status']) + '",'
        '"' + data['requester_name'] + '",'
        '"' + str(data['source']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['responder_id']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['due_by']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['updated_at']) + '",'
        '"' + str(data['frDueBy']) + '",'
        '"' + data['ticket_type'] + '",'
        '"' + str(data['created_at']) + '"'
        ')')
```

when I run I am getting this traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\users\swatson\dropbox\source files\winpython\dash\newTickets.py", line 198, in <module>
main()
 File "c:\users\swatson\dropbox\source files\winpython\dash\newTickets.py", line 159, in main
addNew(n)
File "c:\users\swatson\dropbox\source files\winpython\dash\newTickets.py", line 65, in addNew
'"' + str(data['created_at']) + '"'
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Now I know for a fact (by doing a printstr(data['created_at'])) that there is a value at data['created_at'], and I also know that is is the same value as with data['updated_at'] so I am at a loss as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental mistake here is to try and build a query as one string. **Don't do that**. That way SQL injection vulnerabilities lie.

Use SQL parameters instead:

```
sql_query = ('insert into ithelpdesk ' 
        '(id,display_id,subject,description,priority,status,requester_name,source,responder_id,due_by,updated_at,frDueBy,ticket_type,created_at)'
        ' values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    (data['id'], data['display_id'], data['subject'], data['description'],
     data['priority'], data['status'], data['requester_name'], data['source'], 
     data['responder_id'], data['due_by'], data['updated_at'], data['frDueBy'],
     data['ticket_type'], data['created_at']))
```

The exact syntax depends on your database adapter; it could be you need to use `%s`. Many database adapters also support *named* parameters, in which case you don't even need to pass in 15 separate values. You just name the keys to extract from the dictionary, in the query:

```
sql_query = ('insert into ithelpdesk ' 
        '(id,display_id,subject,description,priority,status,requester_name,source,responder_id,due_by,updated_at,frDueBy,ticket_type,created_at)'
        ' values (:id, :display_id, :subject, :description, '
        '         :priority, :status, :requester_name, :source '
        '         :responder_id, :due_by, :updated_at, :frDueBy, '
        '         :ticket_type, :created_at)',
    data)
```

The Python [DB API standard](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) supports a few different parameter styles. For positional parameters `?` or `%s` can be used, for named, `:name` or `%(name)s`. `sqlite3` uses the first styles, [MySQLDB the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables).

The exception is thrown you are concatenating unicode data with string data, and there is a `None` in there somewhere. Perhaps `data['ticket_type']` is `None`.

Comment: @Stevo_300: MySQLDB uses `%s` instead of `?` for SQL parameters. Not sure if it supports named.

Comment: @Stevo_300: MySQLDB supports `%(name)s` style parameters, so your code could use `%(id)s, %(display_id)s, %(subject)s`, etc.