# How to make an exception of "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found"?

Tags: python

I met this exception and search the network.
But I can't get any information of how to make such an exception.

Could someone give some codes to produce such an exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563003/typeerror-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer-nonetype-found) of a program that produces this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to cast a None to a unicode string somewhere implicitly. My guess is that you'll need to do a `if var is not None` check somewhere.

```
$ python2
>>> u"" + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Note that Python 3.7 will give you a better error message:

```
$ python3
>>> u"" + None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```