# Programming Error in python, How do I parse values of a tuple in a table with SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql

In order to parse the values of  variables a and b in the field  username and password respectively of table admin_details I tried this method the pseudo code  is something like below:

```
...
...
a=4
b=8
....
....
cur.execute("INSERT INTO admin_details(username, password)  VALUES('%s','%s'), %(a,b)")
....
```

I get the value inserted in the table as 
**username: 4 
password:8**

But in order to insert the characters like**
 **a=' john'** 
 **b='snow'**
in the admin_details field.
I tried using tuples as below

```
a='john'
b='snow'
tup=['a','b']
```

and to insert this tuple's value a and b in the table i tried all the possible ways but still I am not able to store the variables in the table.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO admin_details(username, password)  VALUES('%s','%s'), % ['a','b']")
```

But I get this

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO INTO admin_details(username) VALUES('%s'), %('entry1.get()')' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use this way to insert mysql data should be better:

```
insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO admin_details(username, password)  VALUES("{0}","{1}")'.format(*tup)
cur.execute(insert_sql)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not attempt to use string formatting for constructing SQL queries. Pass query parameters in the second argument to `execute()` - this way you'll protect yourself against [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems:

```
a = 'john'
b = 'snow'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO admin_details(username, password) VALUES(%s, %s)", (a, b))
```

Note that in this case you also don't need quotes around the placeholders in the query.

See also:

- [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)