# Comparing date in sql with custom date

Tags: python, sql-server, mariadb, erpnext, frappe

I was trying to compare a custom date with date field in sql.I done the following query but it returned an error and rightfully so. I have my date value in `date1` and want to comapare it with `sale.posting_date`.I tried reading the related posts here,but no use.Can anyone help me?

```
def get_total(filters):
 date1= filters.get("Date")
total_amount=frappe.db.sql("""SELECT SUM(sale.grand_total) FROM `tabSales    Invoice` sale,`tabPayment` payment where payment.parent=sale.name and   sale.posting_date = date1 """ )
return total_amount
```

Comment: Probably these two links could help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: @MaximilianAst I am using  frappe framework . That is why this seems so different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple change and now I cleared that.

```
total_amount=frappe.db.sql("""SELECT SUM(sale.grand_total) FROM `tabSales Invoice` sale where sale.posting_date= %s """ % date1)
```