# mysqldb: error with Select/execute/escape_string

Tags: python, mysql

**executing this code on Python 2.7.10 [GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2**

```
import flask
from MySQLdb import escape_string as thwart
username="abc"

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="pythonprogramming")
c       = conn.cursor()
x       = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)",  (thwart(username)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in TypeError: must be impossible, not str
```

**this is MySQL version on my PC**

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value

+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version | 5.7.11

| protocol_version | 10

| slave_type_conversions |

| tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1

| version | 5.7.11

| version_comment | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64

| version_compile_os | Linux

+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: the above python code has   ----   Import MySQLdb

Comment: Is _import flask_ necessary to reproduce the problem? Try to strip all unneeded code (and unrelated tags).

And try to remove all unneeded complexity. Is it necessary to remove `escape_string` to `thwart`?

Comment: `escape_string` seems to be very important here, but in the headline, there is only `thwart`, which sounds quite random to me. Your question will be hard to find as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked for me and the query variable x returned "1L"

```
`param1="john"
 x = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s """, (param1,))
`
```

**though i did not quite understand why the following code below did not work**

```
param1="john"
x = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s """ % (param1,))
```

**and**

```
param1="john"
x = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s """ , (param1))
```

Comment: 1L is the number 1 as a long integer. This seems to be the size of the result set. Probably the database driver generally uses a long because the size of a result set _could_ exceed the range of an integer.

Comment: Your second try equals `x = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ("john",) """)
    `. Normal string interpolation.

Comment: As for your 3rd try: execute needs a tuple or a hash of values. Just putting parentheses around a single value does _not_ create a tuple. You need the additional comma.

Comment: agreed.. thanks for the clarification. I found the following link quite helpful  http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Answer (score 0):

You are aware of the dangers of SQL injection. That's good.

You even use a very secure form of `execute`: *parametrized query*). When you do your query this way, you do not need escaping at all. `execute` does it all for you. Thus the solution is:

```
x       = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %
```

s", (username,))

You would need escaping if you did something like this (with the needed `import`):

```
x       = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s" %  escape_string(username))
```

For further discussion, have a look at [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)

Comment: >>> import MySQLdb <br>
    >>> from MySQLdb import escape_string <br>
    >>> conn     = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",  passwd="samsam",db="pythonprogramming") <br>
    >>> c        = conn.cursor() <br>
    >>> username ="abc" <br>
    >>> x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)" %  escape_string(username))  <br><br> ...still getting error <br><br><b> 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> <br>
TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not str<br>
>>></b>

Comment: Sorry, the parameters have to be passed as a tuple (or a hash if you use "%(name)s"). Edited.