# total tracking varible using sqlite fetchone

Tags: python, sqlite

I am, having problems trying to sore the output of an sqlite query in a python variable to keep track of a total. I have looked around and seen examples using the c.fetchone() method but I cannot seem to get it to work , I keep getting the error TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '___getitem____' . I don't understand what this means . can anyone help?

```
    i = -1
    i = i + 1

    self.t = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('test2.jpg'))
    self.c.execute("SELECT name FROM item WHERE code = '%s'" % self.t)
    self.listbox.insert(i,self.c.fetchone())
    self.listbox1.insert(i,"£")
    self.c.execute("SELECT price FROM item WHERE code = '%s'" % self.t)
    self.listbox2.insert(i,self.c.fetchone())

    self.y=self.c.fetchone()[i]
    print self.y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the value once and reuse:

```
self.c.execute("SELECT price FROM item WHERE code = %s", (self.t, ))

value = self.c.fetchone()[0]
self.listbox2.insert(i, value)
self.y = value
```

Note how I'm passing the `self.t` value into the query - this is called parameterization and should be preferred comparing to using string formatting to make SQL queries.

Comment: After changing the code to this i get an error message on the line      self.c.execute("SELECT price FROM item WHERE code = %s", (self.t, ))

Operational error near %

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables

i have been reading here and it seems to be the same syntax but im still getting the   Operational error near "%" : Syntax error