# Python-MySQL : removing single quotes around variable values in query while running db.execute(str, vars)

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am running this code

```
    def details(self, dbsettings, payload):
        res = None
        with UseDatabase(dbsettings) as db:
            sql = "select * from %(tablename)s where userid = %(userid)s"
            result = db.run_query_vals(sql, payload)
            res = result.fetchall()
        return res
```

but get an error

> SQLError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''statuser' where userid = '14'' at line 1

The arguments being passed are :

```
sql = "select * from %(tablename)s where userid = %(userid)s"
payload = {'tablename' : 'statuser', 'userid' : 14}
```

As far as I understand, the query being passed to MySQL is along the lines of

> select * from 'statuser' where userid = '14'

which is where I get the error; the tablename isnt supposed to be enclosed in quotes. How do I have the name included without the quotes/make them backquotes?

(I don't want to hard-code the table name - this is a variable and is initialised according to different parameters during class creation). Any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.format()` from string in python:

```
def details(self, dbsettings, payload):
    res = None
    with UseDatabase(dbsettings) as db:
        sql = "select * from {tablename} where userid = {userid}"
        sql = sql.format(**payload)
        # result = db.run_query_vals(sql, payload) # Method to run query
        res = result.fetchall()
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in pymysql and have figured out a solution:

***rewrite the escape method in class 'pymysql.connections.Connection', which obviously adds "'" arround your string.***

don't know whether it will help in your case, just sharing a possible way

similiar question: [How to remove extra quotes in pymysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395887/how-to-remove-extra-quotes-in-pymysql/54175392#54175392)

Here's my code:

```
from pymysql.connections import Connection, converters


class MyConnect(Connection):
    def escape(self, obj, mapping=None):
        """Escape whatever value you pass to it.

        Non-standard, for internal use; do not use this in your applications.
        """
        if isinstance(obj, str):
            return self.escape_string(obj)  # by default, it is :return "'" + self.escape_string(obj) + "'"
        if isinstance(obj, (bytes, bytearray)):
            ret = self._quote_bytes(obj)
            if self._binary_prefix:
                ret = "_binary" + ret
            return ret
        return converters.escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)


config = {'host':'', 'user':'', ...}
conn = MyConnect(**config)
cur = conn.cursor()
```