# The right syntax to use near '''?

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a Python bot which connects to a SQL database and updates values in tables.

I have the following code:

`mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reputation WHERE username = '" + str(critiquer) + "'")`

I am receiving the error "...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1"

I've done some debugging and there is no problem with the string "critiquer," and the row exists in the table.

Would appreciate some insight into this problem.

Comment: `critiquer` may contain a single quote, thus the error.

Comment: @EduardDaduya `critiquer` does not contain a single quote. I've also double checked this by executing the query without a variable, and I am still receiving the error message.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries to avoid this sort of problem.

Comment: Paramaterized queries would both solve the problem of dangling quotes and protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries

Comment: As a very simple debugging step, did you try assembling the query string and then printing it, before executing it?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, it seems to print fine.

Comment: And did you try executing the printed sql statement?

Comment: When you printed the statement, critiquer didn't have any quotes or other odd characters in it?  Did you try pasting the query into a SQL client program and executing it there?

Comment: @EduardDaduya yes, I did try that.

Comment: @JohnGordon I checked it with an SQL client program and it worked fine. There were no weird characters in the critiquer string.

Comment: Can you post the assembled query?  I don't see how it can execute fine inside a SQL client but have trouble inside the python code.

Comment: @JohnGordon [Here is a picture of the execution and error message I receive](http://imgur.com/HTKeQKh) If you don't want to look at the picture, the assembled query is `SELECT * FROM reputation WHERE username = 'ryanbtw'` I've also tested this with different usernames that have rows and I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Does MySQL expect commands to be terminated with a semicolon?  Is `username` a reserved word?

Comment: What is the MySQL server version? And what's your Python version?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a parametrized query:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reputation WHERE username = '?'", critiquer)
```