# Insert fields into MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-workbench

When I try and enter the following command into MySQL:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO event(summary, location, start, end, created, uid, description, calid) VALUES ('Dom seeing Carl - Test', 'City', '2016-11-30 22:30:00+00:00', '2016-11-30 23:00:00+00:00', '2016-11-29 00:39:13+00:00', '80462778A326E04EBD831336D01F2A2F051BA9E0A50E254ABADB036AF2BBE902040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000005096FE958A49D201000000000000000010000000', 'New build happening…', '2')"""
```

I get and Unicode error.

I have tried that same insert directly into MySQL using workbench console and it works flawlessly, I can not understand why is Python complaining.
The Python code I am using is:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.100.1","root","test123","calendar1" )
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
db.close()
```

Table definitions:

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
uid, longtext, NO, , , 
summary, longtext, NO, , , 
location, varchar(255), NO, , , 
start, varchar(45), NO, , , 
end, varchar(45), NO, , , 
description, longtext, NO, , , 
created, varchar(45), NO, , , 
calid, int(11), NO, , ,
```

Traceback error:

```
TypeError: query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple
```

Comment: please post the full traceback error in the question

Comment: and does this datetime format 2016-11-30 22:30:00+00:00 was inserted in mysql?

Comment: also please post ddl of event table

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this other format:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.100.1","root","test123","calendar1" )
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO 
                    event(summary, location, start, end, created, uid, description, calid) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', 
                    ('Dom seeing Carl - Test', 'City', '2016-11-30 22:30:00+00:00', '2016-11-30 23:00:00+00:00', '2016-11-29 00:39:13+00:00', '80462778A326E04EBD831336D01F2A2F051BA9E0A50E254ABADB036AF2BBE902040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000005096FE958A49D201000000000000000010000000', 'New build happening…', '2'))
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
db.close()
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries) is related and gives good points on why using this format is recommended.

Comment: When I try to do it like that it says: 'Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>'

Comment: Could you show the full traceback as well as the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:
@valeas's answer is correct but the `%s` should be enclosed in qoutes as sql would not be able to comprehend the string once strings are substituted in the placeholders `%s` as it will be treated as variables in the final SQL statement.

```
try:
    cursor.execute("insert into event(summary, location, start, end,
        created, uid, description, calid) values('%s', '%s', '%s',
        '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"%('Dom seeing Carl - Test', 'City', '2016-11-30 22:30:00+00:00', '2016-11-30 23:00:00+00:00', '2016-11-29 00:39:13+00:00', '80462778A326E04EBD831336D01F2A2F051BA9E0A50E254ABADB036AF2BBE902040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000005096FE958A49D201000000000000000010000000', 'New build happening…', '2'))
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
```

Comment: Yes that does work, but as per the resolution here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries it should work with the , instead %

Comment: Yes, it works without the %s as in the link you posted, but I am unable to reproduce your error. Can you provide addition information about the table as requested by others. eg:`show create table event`

Comment: Table definitions are added to the initial question at the top.

Comment: Which field are you using as a primary key, any constraints? I need to recreate the db to try to reproduce the error.

Comment: It is a basic test example, it is a database with only one table, no PK no constraints.