# Proper SQL Queries for pre-3.x Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am running a [Water] Meter Data Management system on Linux and Python 2.7. I have been reading SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python).

What is the proper, safe syntax for constructing a query and not having to use the less safe method involving `%s`?

`rc = test_cur.execute("select m.* from meter m where m.acct_no = '%s' ", acct_no)`

I have tried several ways based on the errors I am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` here *does not represent a Python string formatting placeholder*. In this case, this is a MySQL driver [query parameterization placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries). The placeholder(s) are substituted by the database driver with the parameter(s) passed in a separate argument to `execute()`. This is different from regular string formatting.

Note that you don't need quotes around the `%s` in this case - the driver will automatically decide if quotes are needed depending on the parameter type:

```
rc = test_cur.execute("select m.* from meter m where m.acct_no = %s", (acct_no, ))
```

Also note the `acct_no` enclosed in a *tuple*.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful.