# appending many variables to MySQL with python

Tags: python, mysql

```
insert_basic = '""' + '"INSERT INTO info VALUES (' + "'" + testid + "','" + username + "','" + fullname + "','" + firstnumber + "','" + secondnumber + "','" + floatnumber + "','" + posts + "','" + country + '","' + bio + '","' + link + '");'
cur.execute(insert_basic)
try: 
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM basic;""")
print cur.fetchall()
```

Hello, I have done a lot of research and I cannot seem to get the syntax right for submitting to SQL. Some of the variables are integers and some are strings with one being a float.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [*parameterized queries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries) are for:

```
parameters = (testid, username, fullname, firstnumber, secondnumber, floatnumber, posts, country, bio, link)
query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        info 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
cur.execute(query, parameters)
```

When you do it this way, you are letting your *MySQL database driver to handle the type conversions between Python and MySQL automatically*.

And, you are also protecting yourself from [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) that would be easy to apply to your initial code where you string concatenate your query.

---

I would also *specify the table column names in this case explicitly*:

```
INSERT INTO 
    info 
    (column_name1, column_name2, ...)
VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```