# Python MySQLdb is not inserting all the records

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm stuck working on an Python script. This script should to populate a MySQL table getting values from select statement.

The problem is when I get the values from the select statement, insert into statement doesn't work correctly and not insert all the records. I have check the same select statement in MySQL WorkBench and returns the correct number of records that I want to put in the destination table. The select statement is this and the number of rows expected are more than 100.000 (is a big database):

```
SELECT MAX(c1),MAX(c2),MAX(c3),MAX(c4),c5,c6,MAX(c7)
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
INNER JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id
WHERE c4 NOT LIKE '%A%'
GROUP BY t1.c1;
```

This select statement should return records that not contains 'A' character.

And this is my Python code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,pass,dbName)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(c1),MAX(c2),MAX(c3),MAX(c4),c5,c6,MAX(c7)
     FROM Table1 as t1
     INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
     INNER JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id
     WHERE c4 NOT LIKE '%A%'
     GROUP BY t1.c1")

results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DestinationTable(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"
         %(str(row[1]),str(row[2]),str(row[3]),str(row[4]),str(row[5]),str(row[6]))
   db.commit()
```

I think the problem is in the Insert into statement, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` all in one execute call?

Comment: I think that you propose is a slow statement, and I don't know if its  optimal...maybe I'm wrong sorry

Comment: You avoid looping and all processes are handled in MySQL engine.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I'm going to try it

Answer (score 2):

Simply run an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` instead of `...VALUES` which does not require looping or SQL string interpolation (which should be [parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/775296/1422451) anyway).

Below `MAX(c1)` is removed from `SELECT` statement since you skip it in attempted query:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO DestinationTable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
       SELECT MAX(c2), MAX(c3), MAX(c4), c5, c6, MAX(c7)
       FROM Table1 as t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
       INNER JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id
       WHERE c4 NOT LIKE '%A%'
       GROUP BY t1.c1"

cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Parfait I have tried it but not works, some results are lost.

Comment: How can that be? Check types between `SELECT` columns and corresponding columns in `INSERT INTO`. Be sure they align. Additionally, you might have table constraints like primary keys/indexes disallowing dup records. Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE DestinationTable` output.