# Passing parameter into pandas to query mysql data via read_sql_query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to pass a parameter to a pandas dataframe database query but I cant quite get the syntax right. What am I missing? This works for [default python, not pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries) and unfortunately the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) dont help. I also tried googling the standard mentioned with no luck. My query works fine when I replace the `%s` with the actual category id

```
sqlQuery='''SELECT aa.*
    FROM ballot aa
    WHERE categoryId = %s
       '''
df1=pd.read_sql_query(sqlQuery,connectionObject,'529') #trying to pass in 529
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just format the string as I pass it to `read_sql`

```
df = pd.read_sql(sqlQuery % '529', connectionObject)
```