# Python MySQL(MariaDB) query FROM_UNIXTIME I get count not result (Showing rows 0 - 0 )

Tags: python, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I need to get result on python: 2018-12-10 06:15:36 but I get: 1 (count i think) as result when i use this:

On python:

```
>>> dateadd = g.cur.execute("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') FROM videos WHERE id={}".format(id))
>>> print dateadd
1
```

On phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') FROM videos WHERE id=1
```

> Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0014 seconds.)

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')   date
2018-12-10 06:15:36                        1544465736
```

How do i get data time (2018-12-10 06:15:36) when I use print function on python ?

Solved:

```
>>> g.cur.execute("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') FROM videos WHERE id={}".format(id))
>>> dateadd = g.cur.fetchone()
>>> print dateadd[0]
2018-12-16 10:53:16
```

Thanks to @kcorlidy

Comment: try to use `g.cur.fetchall()` or `g.cur.fetchone()`. `dateadd` just the status whether executed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g.cur.execute` will return the status whether executed successfully. You don't need to concern about it too much. After you executed successfully,  you should use `fetchone`, `fetchall`, `fetchmany` to gain result. And one more thing you should know that using param is a better choice, it can avoid most of sql injection. [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries)

```
g.cur.execute("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS value FROM videos WHERE id=%s",(id))
```