# MySQL cur.execute with format

Tags: python, mysql

I don't properly understand how to use `.format` for SQL statement in my case.
Can I use it to define a column name?

It works with one value, but not with whole tuples.

```
sql_stmt = ("""UPDATE intmt_vals SET {0} = {1} WHERE ID={2};""".format(column, values, ids))
cur.execute(sql_stmt)
```

`column` is a key from an outter dict `column = k`, e.g. `'column1'`

`values` are values from inner dict, `vals = tuple(dict.get(k).values())` e.g. `(a, b, c, d, e, f,)`

`ids` are keys from inner dict, e.g. `ids = tuple(dict.get.(k).keys())`.e.g 
`(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Error 
`mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and it is easy to do. But you should only use `format` on setting columns name. Reason: [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-parameterized-queries). And why you got `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` is your sql statement only have one column but multiple value, like `column1 = (a, b, c, d, e, f)`.

```
sql = "UPDATE test SET {col} = %s WHERE {col} = %s;"

data = {"a":"b","c":"d"}
print(data.items())
try:
    cur.executemany(sql.format(col="msg"),data.items())
    con.commit()
except Exception as e:
    con.rollback()
    raise e
```

Comment: `sql = "UPDATE intmt_vals SET   {col1} = %s WHERE {col2} =%s"`. _expression expected got {_ Strange, That's what about IntelliJ warns.

Comment: But this statement is fine in Python syntax. because your final sql_stmt will be `"UPDATE intmt_vals SET col1 = %s WHERE col2 =%s"`. And it is safe if others can not control col value.

Comment: In another way to express it, try this code `a = "This is: {}".format("ad")
print(a.format("bcde"))`. After you used `format` to the string, the string value will be changed and `{}` will be spent.

Comment: Yep, got it. Final `sql = "UPDATE test SET {0} = %s WHERE {1} = %s;".format(col1,col2)`. Do you mean, there is no possibility for a SQL injection even with `format`?

Comment: Nope, if other can change your col1 or col2 value. Because `format` insert data into string straightly. But it is easy to solve it by using regex to check whether col's value is legal.

Comment: My first and second comment is to explain your final sql_statement will not contain `{}`, so you need not to care about IntelliJ warns.