# Use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE from python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use this code to update a table on mySQL, but I'm getting error with the update part

```
table_name = 'my_table'
sql_select_Query = """ 
INSERT {0}  (age, city, gender,UniqueId)
VALUES ({1},{2},{3},{4})
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  age=VALUES(age,city=VALUES(city),gender=VALUES(gender),height=VALUES(height)
""".format(table_name,  '877','2','1','2898989')

    cursor = mySQLconnection .cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    mySQLconnection.commit()
```

For example, to update the city I get:

```
Unknow columns '877'
```

Hence it seems it is taking the value as a column name and search for then in my_table.

Comment: As a start I would print out the final sql query after the substitutions have been made.

Comment: You also seem to be missing a closing parenthesis after `age`, it should be `age=values(age)`

Comment: age=VALUES(age must be age=VALUES(age) but your string doesn't look like the parameterized mysql i come to know

Comment: @nbk this is not a parametrized query, this is string interpolation.

Comment: You are also missing `height` from the field list, while you have it in the update section.

Comment: i know, but the nonsense on this page is to use parametrized statement sql imnjection and all that. besides it is easier to read

Comment: You can't use `VALUES(height)` if `height` isn't one of the columns you're inserting into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use parameters with Python is to pass the values in the `execute()` call, not to interpolate the values into the SQL query.

Except for identifiers like the table name in your case.

```
sql_select_Query = """
INSERT `{0}`  (age, city, gender, UniqueId)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  age=VALUES(age), city=VALUES(city), gender=VALUES(gender)
""".format(table_name)

cursor.execute(sql_select_Query, ('877', '2', '1', '2898989'))
```

See also [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries)

You forgot the `)` after `VALUES(age`. Maybe that was just a typo you made transcribing the question into Stack Overflow. I've fixed it in the example above.

Your INSERT statement sets the `height` column, but it's not part of the tuple you insert. I removed it in the example above. If you want `height` in the UPDATE clause, then you need to include it in the tuple and pass a value in the parameters.

Also I put back-quotes around the table name, just in case the table name is a reserved keyword or contains a space or something.