# How to pass variable in mysql Where clause

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pass a variable in mysql Query but its keep giving error.

I am referign to this 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="111.222.333.444.555",
  user="user",
  passwd="pass",
  database="database_aname"
)
#print(mydb)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

#lon=((data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['@timestamp']))

  query = ("SELECT * from device_stock join customers on device_stock.user_id=customers.id  WHERE device_stock.imei=%s")
  #query = ("SELECT * from device_stock join customers on device_stock.user_id=customers.id  WHERE device_stock.imei=0351777090784867")

  mycursor.execute(query,(imei))

 for row in mycursor:
        print (row)
```

but it gives bellow error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

mycursor.execute(query,(imei))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 537, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 
`mycursor.execute(query,(imei,))`

(imei) is not taken as a tuple.