# Mysql not able to insert row in table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert rows into an empty table. I am doing this by mysql statements inside python code. But when I am trying to insert a row I am getting error. Please help.

Note that mostly I am inserting fresh data, so almost always the else part gets executed.

Python code:

```
def dbsupport_update_table(dbcon, name, exam_report):
    """
    Update current table and modified date in database
    for the name.
    """
    dbcur = dbcon.cursor()

    now = dt.utcnow()

    dbtable = get_latest_table_data()
    dbdict = dbtable.set_index('name').T.to_dict('list')

    if name in dbdict.keys():
        # Modify existing data
        sql=("update student_table set last_updated_date='%s', first_marks=%g, second_marks=%g, third_marks=%g, "
                "fourth_marks=%g where name='%s'" 
                % (now,  exam_report[0],  exam_report[1],  exam_report[2],
                     exam_report[3], name))
    else:
        # Insert fresh row
        column_str = ("name, last_updated_date, first_marks, second_marks, third_marks, fourth_marks")  
        insert_str = (name, 0, exam_report[0], exam_report[1], exam_report[2], exam_report[3])
        sql = ("insert into student_table (%s) values (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str))

    dbcur.execute(sql)
    #dbcur.executemany(sql, daily_data)
    dbcon.commit()

    print("Successfully added data for %s to DB" % (name))
```

When executing I am getting below error.

```
File "data_retrieval_new.py", line 96, in dbsupport_update_table
    if name in dbdict.keys():
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

The table is defined as thus:

```
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated_date | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_marks       | decimal(19,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| second_marks      | decimal(19,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| third_marks       | decimal(19,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fourth_marks      | decimal(19,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Dump the exact contents of the `sql` variable into your question too

Comment: As per comment from Caius, I am dumping sql variable below. When I did that I figured out the problem that was causing the error. It was because of the double paranthesis around the values of the row.
 
The value of sql variable is:
```"insert into student_table (name, last_updated_date, first_marks, second_marks, third_marks, fourth_marks) values (('John', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))"
```
Now can anyone tell me how to make this single paranthesis?

Comment: we could, but it would still leave the sql injection vulnerability to deal with. Take a read of the bottom of my answer; python is one of those rare languages where writing safe parameterized sql is actually easier than writing unsafe string concatenated ones, so give it a go..

Comment: Are you familiar with INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Comment: Also, please see normalisation. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

"Column count doesn't match value count" occurs when you run an insert statement and the number of columns doesn't match the number of values, for example:

```
insert into person(name)          values('John',23,'new York')
insert into person(name,age,city) values('John')
```

Look at the contents of the sql variable you're actually executing and I think you'll pretty quickly see the problem

The next thing you should do, and this is a vital thing you must do forever more in your programming career, is absorb and apply the knowledge at https://bobby-tables.com

If you do that, not only will your problem go away, but your code will be considerably more resistant to hacking

---

Edit:

I'm not a python dev - this is the first python I've ever written. I think, based on the advice from bobby-tables.com it would go like this:

```
else:
    # Insert fresh row 
    val = (name, 0, exam_report[0], exam_report[1], exam_report[2], exam_report[3])
    sql = ("insert into student_table (name, last_updated_date, first_marks, second_marks, third_marks, fourth_marks) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

dbcur.execute(sql, vals)
```

But based on [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries) I think this might be better:

```
vals_dictionary = {
    'nam': name,
    'lud': 0,
    'fim': exam_report[0],
    'sem': exam_report[1],
    'thm': exam_report[2],
    'fom': exam_report[3]
}
dbcur.execute ("""
    insert into student_table (name, last_updated_date, first_marks, second_marks, third_marks, fourth_marks) 
    values (%(nam)s, %(lud)s, %(fim)s, %(sem)s, %(thm)s, %(fom)s)        
        """, vals_dictionary)
```

As noted, I'm not a python dev, so this might need some tweaking

Comment: The problem is not number of columns as I have double checked the commas and number of columns

Comment: MySQL thinks the value list you're passing has only one value-the problem is hence the number of columns, caused by the extra parentheses but honestly.. parameterize this and your life gets easier, safer and the problem goes away. What's not to love?

Comment: hi. i didnt exactly understood your answer. can you give example from my code itself how to parameterize this?

Comment: if you give a separate answer with parameterize example, i would select it as answer.

Comment: I edited in what I guess is a parameterized example, but check it and if you needed to change anything to get it working, feel free to suggest an edit to my answer