# MySQL Python connector error while inserting

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

So I am trying to build a database in MySQL using python. I already created the database and created the table I want to use. it's called '***alliances***'.

Now this table only has two columns, an ID column and a alliance_name column.
The ID's auto increment , and the names I already have them as a list and would like to insert them into the table one by one. but it gives me an error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'alliance' in 'field list'
```

this is my code :

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "#########", database = 'WANHUI')

mycursor = db.cursor()

# mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE WANHUI")  we already added to the db

# mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE alliances (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, alliance_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL) ")

mini_list = alliance_list[:30]   # we only need the first 30

for alliance in mini_list: 
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES (alliance)")
    db.commit()
```

Why does it say no 'alliance' column if i do specify in the query to insert into the alliance_name
and that 'alliance' is the string that I wish to insert ??

EDIT:
I already tried this version:

```
for alliance in mini_list: 
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES (%s)", (alliance))
    db.commit()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(Iron Brotherhood Alliance), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

and even if I do :

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES (%s)", (mini_list))
db.commit()
```

it would give me this :

```
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: Duplicate of [MySQL parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parameterize your query like this:

```
for alliance in mini_list: 
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES (%s)", (alliance, ))
    db.commit()
```

Then you can go further and make a batch insert with one query, by prebuilding its statement string, instead of executing multiple calls to your database.
Let's assume your `mini_list` is equal to something like this: `["aa", "bb", "cc"]`.

```
# You get a string "('aa'), ('bb'), ('cc')" here for `VALUES` part of your SQL query:
alliances = ", ".join(f"('{alliance}')" for alliance in mini_list)


# Now use the string `alliances` to build a query:
mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES {alliances}")
db.commit()
```

This will produce SQL: `INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES ('aa'), ('bb'), ('cc')` and will allow you to insert all alliances at once.

Another way and the easier one to achieve the same result is to use [`cursor.executemany()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), that will produce the same query:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO alliances (alliance_name) VALUES (%s)",
                   [(alliance, ) for alliance in mini_list])
```

Comment: But what if I want to insert one by one? why will it not work?

Comment: Inserting one by one is also acceptable, but makes more calls to the database, so if you already have a collection of items to insert, it's better to insert a batch using one query to the database to reduce the load on it.