# Cannot insert integer to MySQL in python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

In my flask application, I cannot insert `user_id` which I get from `request.form`
and it is an integer to MySQL. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
from flask import request
import socket
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '192.168.0.101'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3307'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'msblog_users'
 
mysql = MySQL(app)   

@app.route("/create_post", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def create_post():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "You can only send post requests here!"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.form.get('user_id')
        message = request.form.get('message')
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post)VALUES (%s, %s)''', (int(user_id), message))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return "Done"
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What should I do? I did lots of search but so far nothing!

Comment: Please post the full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` stands for string, if you want you want that parameters to be an integer, make it `%i`.

```
INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post)VALUES (%i, %s) ....
```

If the column `post` is a string / text column (varchar probably) you should also quote it as such.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES (%i , '%s')" % (1, 'string value')
```

*By the way, this is the old way of formatting strings*

The new way is doing this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES ({}, '{}')".format(1, 'string value')
```

Or you can name the parameters:

```
"INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post) VALUES ({id}, '{str}')".format( str='string value',id=1)
```

Comment: I Still got the same error with %i  and 1

Comment: There's only the `%s` placeholder. Do *not* quote placeholders. Do *not* `%` interpolate placeholders, because then they're not placeholders anymore, but just injection-prone string interpolations. The parameterised SQL placeholder mechanism is *not* Python string interpolation, even if it looks very similar.

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/775399/476 

Comment: @deceze, my bad, you're right.... Anyway I just sent a string, the parameters are not sent as an 2nd argument to execute.

Comment: I tried both ways but I got the same error

Comment: @SajadKamali did you try with the "" % (...,...) ? then you sent a plain sql string, which is NOT escaped (so *not* with a comma). You can try to create first manual a SQL INSERT without the parameters. Maybe something else is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the `int(user_id)` part, specifically due to the value being `None`. You should first make sure it is a valid integer:

```
try:
    user_id = int(request.form.get('user_id'))
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    return <error 400>
```

Comment: the value is not empty even when I manually put 1 I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem.
It's so strange!! the problem was not even related to the insert query. Take a look at the MySQL connection configuration part in my flask code, as you can see below:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '192.168.0.101'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3307'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'msblog_users'
```

the port is written between quotations! it's a string but MySQL needs an integer value for the port to be able to connect!

here is the quick fix:

```
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3307
```

It took me a day to solve it!

Comment: Posting the full error trace back would have probably helped find that more quickly…