# python mysql - can not delete row from database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, linux, database

I am trying to delete a row from my database but nothing worked. here is my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="1",database="workers")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
query = "DELETE FROM `workers` WHERE id = %s"
# connect to the database server
# execute the query
mycursor.execute(query, (1,)) 
mysql.commit()  # You need to commit the transaction
```

Note: I am using python3.10, and my operating system is ubuntu. I also try to use %d instead of %s, but it does not work.

Comment: I linked to a duplicate question about INSERT, but the same answer applies to DELETE or any other SQL statement: use `%s` for query parameters, not `%d`. It's unfortunate that the connector uses `%s`, the same placeholder as Python string formatting, because parameters are not in fact string formatting. Many developers get confused by this.

Comment: @BillKarwin even %s does not work.I already tried.

Comment: By 'it doesn't work',  do you get an error?  Are you sure there exists an entry with ```id = 1```?  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test table:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.2.0     |
+-----------+

mysql> create table workers (id serial primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into workers values (1), (2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from workers;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Demo script delete-test.py:

```
import mysql.connector

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = { ... }

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    # FIXED: use %s instead of %d
    query = "DELETE FROM `workers` WHERE id = %s"

    mycursor.execute(query, (1,))

    # FIXED: mydb instead of mysql 
    mydb.commit()

    mycursor.close()
    mydb.close()
```

Run script:

```
% python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
% python3 ./delete-test.py
%
```

Check results:

```
mysql> select * from workers;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```

Comment: you are a true magician! Thank you very much for your assistance. I have a follow-up question. I am currently using a threading pool in Python and I am curious as to why I need to renew my connection to the MySQL server in each thread after calling the fetchall method. If you could provide some insight on this matter, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That sounds like a totally different question, unrelated to the one I gave a solution for. I suggest you post it as a new question, and include the relevant code, so that someone can have the context to answer it. Cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I have made the necessary changes to my code based on your post . However, I encountered an issue where my thread stops running after executing the delete query, even though the query was successful.

Comment: The occurrence of these issues is a result of executing mydb.commit(). If I remove this row, everything functions properly. However, the delete query is not executed.

Comment: If the thread is hanging, is it because there is a lock on the table , held by another client?  Alternatively if it is because you're reusing a MySql `connector`, it might be time to raise another thread/question.

Comment: The OP did ask a new question for the thread pause issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77527080/python-mysql-thread-paused-after-executing-a-delete-query