# how to query a server-side database from a client with mysql and Python

Tags: python, mysql, sockets

I'm trying to create a small Client/Server application with python's Socket module, just for testing purposes to find a suitable formula to integrate it into my project. I'd also like to point out that this is my first time using Sockets and the threading module, so please bear with my code and correct the parts you think could be improved.
my server code server_db.py:

```
import socket
import ast
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='localhost',
                    user='root',
                    password='root',
                    database='mmdb'
                )
    print("Nous sommes connectés à la base de données...")
    cur = conn.cursor()
except mysql.errorcode as err:
    print(err)

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.bind((host, port))
mySocket.listen()

while 1:
    connexion, adresse = mySocket.accept()
    msgClient = connexion.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
    cur.execute(msgClient)
    resultat = cur.fetchall()
    resultat_str = str(resultat)
    connexion.send(resultat_str.encode('utf8'))
    msgClient = connexion.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
    connexion.close()
    ch = input("<R>ecommencer <T>erminer ? ")
    if ch.upper() == "T":
        break
mySocket.close()
```

my code client_db.py:

```
import socket, threading
import ast

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000

class ThreadEmission(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = conn 

    def run(self):
        ident = 2
        pays='Guinée'
        msgClient = "SELECT * FROM ami where fk_identreprise={ident} AND paysAmi={pays};"
        self.connexion.send(msgClient.encode('utf8'))
        self.connexion.close()

class ThreadReception(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = conn 

    def run(self):
        msgServeur = self.connexion.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        resultat = ast.literal_eval(msgServeur)
        print(resultat)
        print(type(resultat))
            
myClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
myClient.connect((host, port))

th_E = ThreadEmission(myClient)
th_R = ThreadReception(myClient)    
th_E.start()
th_R.start()
```

In my client code, I have created two threads, the send thread to send a request to the server and another receive thread to receive the result of my request.
but when I run my code, I'm told that the variable pays, which is 'Guinea', doesn't exist on the server side:
[erreur coté serveur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJzHX.png)

However, this query should return something because in my database there is a  table 'ami' whose 'paysAmi' column has a value of 'Guinée'.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2LfE.png)

So maybe it's my request that's not good, and if so, how should I word it?

Comment: Note that when you write `"{ident}"`, the value of ident is not substituted into the string. You're likely thinking of f-strings. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: You should also think about using SQL parameterization, as using string interpolation in this manner is often vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection). See here for an example of doing parameterization in Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries

Comment: Also, with a TCP stream you will need a framing scheme – a `recv(1024)` is not guaranteed to receive exactly 1024 bytes.

Comment: can you improve my code with your comments?

Comment: @BorrisKouadjaNIANGORAN: Why don't you yourself improve your own code based on the comments? What have you tried? How did you get stuck?

Comment: In `self.connexion.send(msgClient.encode('utf8'))` you are sending `'SELECT * FROM ami where fk_identreprise={ident} AND paysAmi={pays};'`, but you should be sending `SELECT * FROM ami where fk_identreprise=2 AND paysAmi='Guinée';` instead. Send the correct string, and see what happens (also update your question). Also comments by others are very relevant, please take a look.

Comment: OK, thanks, I've solved that problem.